# How do I move my git repo down level in the directory tree?

Tags: c#, git

I'm currently writing an app in C# using using Visual Studio. As such, VS2010 created a Solution directory with my project directories inside. 
So my Hierarchy is like this:

```
Solution  
  .git
  project1
  project2
```

What I'd like to do is make it like this:

```
Solution
  Project 1
    .git
  Project 2
```

As of right now the files in the solution are tracked, except for the project 2 (so stuff like project.sln for example).
Is there a way I can do this without rewriting the history?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually by SethRobinson on #git@freenode.net but here was his solution:

> Step one, move the entire git tree into the subdirectory:

```
mkdir .solution;
mv Solution .solution/Project1; 
mv .solution Solution; 
mkdir Solution/Project2
```

> Step two, tell git to promote the subdirectory into the root:

```
cd Project1; 
mkdir .foo; 
mv * .foo; 
cd .foo; 
mv Project1/* ..; 
cd ..; 
rm -rf .foo; 
git add -A .; 
git commit -a -m "Promoted Project1 to root"
```

Comment: Thanks for finding and posting the solution. Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the tracked files in your repository currently consist of files and directories, all within the "project1" subdirectory.  Since everything is withing the project1 subdirectory, you'd essentially just like to start your repository there.  Is that correct?

If that's true, then you cannot do that without either (1) rewriting your project history (something `git filter-branch` can help you with), or (2) adding history by adding a commit that moves all the files.

Basically, you can't retroactively change things without changing the commit IDs; this is a feature of git.  But your situation **is** addressable.  Just let us know which option your prefer, and we'd be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks bob, I think the answer I posted does number two, which is perfectly fine. When I said I didn't want to alter the history I mean I didn't want git to lose the history it already saved.

Answer (score 0):

if project 2 is not tracked at all, i think you'd just be able to move it to where you want it. git tracks changes to content separate from the tree structure so it will see the files as just moved around, but no content change.

Comment: No, that didn't work, it detects the files in project as new files.

Answer (score 0):

`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter Project\ 1 HEAD`

This does adjust history though.

I tested it like so:

```
root/
  .git
  folder/
    index
```

`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter folder HEAD`

And got:

```
root/
  .git
  index
```